# Gulp4. "AssertionError : Task never defined" when calling or importing tasks

Tags: gulp

Below you can see simplified view of an issue. Basically, I'm able to call **task1.js** using gulp.series in tasks **task2,3.js**, but once I add same code to call **task1.js** in **task4.js** - `Task never defined: task1` error gets thrown.
There are more tasks in the tasks folder than in file structure example below.

I've got three tasks,

```
...
/tasks
   build.js
   clean.js
   dev.js
gulpfile.babel.js
...
```

all of them required in gulpfile.babel.js using the require-dir package

```
import requireDir from 'require-dir';
requireDir('./tasks', {recurse: true});
```

This allows me to call a task from *clean.js* at **dev.js**, and it works fine.

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
gulp.task('dev', gulp.series('clean');
```

But after I add same code structure at **build.js**.

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean');
```

it somehow breaks gulp stream (I guess), so now on any task call I get: 

**$gulp dev**

*-AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: clean*.

---

**$gulp -v**

```
[11:50:11] CLI version 2.0.1
[11:50:11] Local version 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

For those migrating from gulp v3 to v4 or are using `gulp.task()` to define tasks in gulp v4 and get this error message: `Task never defined`, the problem usually lies here:

> **Forward references**
>
> A forward reference is when you compose tasks, using string
>   references, that haven't been registered yet. This was a common
>   practice in older versions, but this feature was removed to achieve
>   faster task runtime and promote the use of named functions. In newer
>   versions, you'll get an error, with the message "Task never defined",
>   if you try to use forward references. You may experience this when
>   trying to use exports for your task registration and composing tasks
>   by string. In this situation, use named functions instead of string
>   references.
>
> During migration, you may need to use the forward reference registry.
>   This will add an extra closure to every task reference and
>   dramatically slow down your build. Don't rely on this fix for very
>   long.

From [gulpjs documentation re: gulp.series](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series#forward-references) and [gulp.parallel documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel#forward-references).

Here is what that means.  There are two ways to create tasks:

```
1.  gulp.task('someStringAsTask', function() {..})   

2.  function myNamedFunction () {…}
```

When you use version 1 (`gulp.task…`) you cannot refer to that task by its string name until it has been registered.  So you cannot do this:

```
exports.sync = gulp.series('sass2css', serve, watch);
// or gulp.task('dev', gulp.series('sass2css', serve, watch);  doesn't work either    

gulp.task('sass2css', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.sass.stylesFile)
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.temp))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
})
```

Results in

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: sass2css
```

That is a forward reference, composing a task (using `gulp.series` or `gulp.parallel`) and referring to a task by its string name (in the above case `'sass2css'`) **before** it has been registered.  (calling "`gulp.task(…..)`" is the act of registering)  Putting the `gulp.task('sass2css',...)` first fixes the problem.

If you use version two of defining a task:

```
function sass2css() {
  return gulp.src(paths.sass.stylesFile)
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.temp))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
}
```

you are now using a **named function** to register a task and do not need to use its name as a string.  So this now works:

```
exports.sync = gulp.series(sass2css, serve, watch);
// gulp.task('dev', gulp.series(sass2css, serve, watch);  this also works
```

**followed** by (or preceded by - either works):

```
function sass2css() {
  return gulp.src(paths.sass.stylesFile)
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.temp))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
}
```

The original OP used this and it worked:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
gulp.task('dev', gulp.series('clean');
```

Noted that `clean.js` got imported before `dev.js` so that was okay.

This didn't work:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean');
```

because the string-referenced task, `'clean'` gets imported (and thus registered) after `build.js` where it is referenced - thus creating an illegal **forward reference** to a string-referenced task.

So there are two standard ways to fix this error:

1. Use named functions to define tasks not `gulp.task('someTask',...)`.  Then it doesn't matter the order of using those named functions when composing other tasks, i.e., when using `gulp.series` or `gulp.parallel`.  And there are other advantages to using named functions, such as passing arguments, so this is the best option.
2. If you do use the older gulp v3 `gulp.task` method of creating tasks with string references, be careful to not refer to those tasks until **after** the task is actually created.

**Also see my answer at [task never defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032147/convert-gulp-watch-in-gulp3-9-1-to-gulp4/55033313#55033313) for fixing another problem which results in the same error message.**  Specifically using `gulp.task('someTask', ['anotherTask'], function(){})` synatx in a gulp4 file.

Comment: Freaking phenomenal answer. Bow in respect! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 16):

The `series` and `parallel` functions of gulp 4 do not create a task definition as its [README](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/README.md) seems to suggest, but instead they both run the tasks in parameter. In order to work as intended, one need to surround the call with a closure.

So, to fix the excerpt

```
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean'));
```

it is necessary to add the closure:

```
// Older EcmaScripts:
gulp.task('build', function() { return gulp.series('clean') });

// EcmaScript 6:
gulp.task('build', () => gulp.series('clean'));
```

Comment: This gives the type error "TS2345: Argument of type '() => TaskFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TaskFunction'."

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar setup where I had recursively `require`'d all tasks under a directory. And after updating to gulp 4 started getting error *Task never defined*.

I tried Pedro solution, but this caused another error:

```
The following tasks did not complete: default
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

The solution was fairly simple for me, just import the missing tasks.

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import './clean';

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clean'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution might be using the official [undertaker-forward-reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/undertaker-forward-reference) package:

```js
const gulp = require("gulp");
const FwdRef = require("undertaker-forward-reference");

gulp.registry(FwdRef()); // Or gulp.registry(new FwdRef());

gulp.task("firstRegisteredTask", gulp.series("laterRegisteredTask")); // Works thanks to undertaker-forward-reference

gulp.task("laterRegisteredTask", () => {
  return gulp.src("someGlob").pipe(gulp.dest("someFolder"));
});
```

This solution might negatively affect performance though ([source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v4.0.2/docs/api/series.md#forward-references)):

> This will add an extra closure to every task reference and dramatically slow down your build.