# Convert gulp watch in gulp@3.9.1 to gulp@4

Tags: javascript, css, npm, gulp

We are switching from `gulp@3.9.1` to `gulp@4` and are having trouble switching over. When we run `gulp watch`, we are getting the following errors and trying to figure out how to resolve it.

**What is the proper way to convert the `gulp watch` task to work with `gulp@4`?**

**Error message**

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: `minify-css`

**Command: `gulp watch`**

- This should run `minify-js` then `minify-css` in order
- `minify-js` should run after `clean-scripts` has completed successfully
- `minify-css` should run after `clean-css` has completed successfully

**Current tasks.**

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    
var src = {
  js: 'js/some-dir/**/*.js',
  css: 'css/some-dir/**/*.css'
};

var dest = {
  js: 'js/dest/some-dir/**/*.js',
  css: 'css/dest/some-dir/**/*.css'
};

gulp.task('clean-css', function() {
  return gulp.src(dest.css)
             .pipe(clean({read:false, force: true});
});

gulp.task('minify-css', ['clean-css'], function() {
  gulp.src(src.css)
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.css));
});

gulp.task('clean-scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(dest.js)
             .pipe(clean({read:false, force: true});
});

gulp.task('minify-js', ['clean-scripts'], function() {
   gulp.src(src.js)
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.js));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['minify-js', 'minify-css'], function() {
  gulp.watch(src.js, ['minify-js']);
  gulp.watch(src.css, ['minify-css']);
});
```

**We tried doing this, but it resulted in the error message**

```js
gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('minify-js', 'minify-css', function() {
  gulp.watch(src.js, ['minify-js']);
  gulp.watch(src.css, ['minify-css']);
}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend converting your `minify-js`, `minify-css`, `clean-scripts` and `clean-css` tasks to functions:

```
var dest = {
  js: 'js/dest/some-dir/**/*.js',
  css: 'css/dest/some-dir/**/*.css'
};

function cleanCss() {
  return gulp.src(dest.css)
             .pipe(clean({read:false, force: true});
});

function minifyCss() {
  return gulp.src(src.css)
             .pipe(cssmin())
             .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.css));
});

function cleanScripts() {
  return gulp.src(dest.js)
             .pipe(clean({read:false, force: true});
});

function minifyJs() {
   return gulp.src(src.js)
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.js));
});

var minifyJsAndClean = gulp.series(minifyJs, cleanScripts);
var minifyCssAndClean = gulp.series(minifyCss, cleanCss);
var watchers = function (done) {
   gulp.watch(src.js, minifyJs);
   gulp.watch(src.css, minifyCss);
   done();
}

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series(minifyJsAndClean, minifyCssAndClean, watchers));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
gulp.task('minify-css', gulp.series('clean-css', function() {
  return gulp.src(src.css)
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.css));
}));

gulp.task('minify-js', gulp.series('clean-scripts', function() {
   return gulp.src(src.js)
       .pipe(uglify())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.js));
}));

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('minify-js', 'minify-css', function() {
  gulp.watch(src.js, gulp.series('minify-js'));
  gulp.watch(src.css, gulp.series('minify-css'));
}));
```

As @Abdaylan suggested, I also advocate switching to functions.  Nevertheless, so you can see where your code was wrong, I have fixed it here.  Gulp 4 does **not** use this syntax:

```
gulp.task('someTask', ['task1', 'task2'], function () {});  // gulp 3
```

Gulp 4:

```
gulp.task('someTask', gulp.series('task1', 'task2', function () {}));  // gulp 4 with string tasks
```

or `gulp.parallel`.  So you can use your `gulp.task` syntax (rather than named functions) if you modify them to use the signatures that gulp 4 supports as I did in your modified code at the top of this answer.

Gulp 4 with named functions:

```
gulp.task(someTask, gulp.series(task1, task2, function () {}));  // gulp 4 with named functions
```

So with named functions, the tasks are not referred to as strings.

See also [task never defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505275/gulp4-assertionerror-task-never-defined-when-calling-or-importing-tasks/54939126#54939126) for other potential problems when migrating from gulp3 to gulp4 with the same error message.

Comment: moving to the `named function` implementation solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this a couple days ago myself. What worked for me was to run each task in its own `gulp.watch()` with the `gulp.series()` on the watch task call instead of the watch task itself. For example:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(src.js, gulp.series('minify-js'));
  gulp.watch(src.css, gulp.series('minify-css'));
});
```