# Gulp function not working after updating to version 4

Tags: gulp

I have updated Gulp 3.9 to 4 and my gulp task is now returning an Assertion Error: Task function must be specified.

Can anyone show how I could refactor the code below to work with Gulp 4?

Thanks in advance!

```
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("./scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("./js/main.js", ['javascript']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'browser-sync', function () {
    gulp.watch("./scss/**/*.scss", 'sass');
    gulp.watch("./js/main.js", 'javascript');
}));
```

should do it.  The function signature has changed (from 3 to 2 parameters) and you need to use `gulp.series`.

See [Convert gulp watch in gulp@3.9.1 to gulp@4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032147/convert-gulp-watch-in-gulp3-9-1-to-gulp4/55033313#55033313)

Answer (score 0):

```
// compile scss into css
function style() {
    // 1. where is my scss file
    return gulp.src('./app/scss/**/*.scss')
    // 2. pass that file through sass compiler
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    // 3. where do I save the compiled CSS?
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/css'))
    // 4. stream changes to all browser
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watch() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './app/'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./app/scss/**/*.scss', style);
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('./app/js/**/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.watch = watch;
```

Faced same issue and I found this code in this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgMQeLymAdU)

Hope this helps.